# Postgres + Play 2.2.1 Java - Driver not found : [ org.postgresql.Driver ]

Tags: postgresql, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to connect the sample 'computer-database-jpa' to postgres , but I cant.
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database-jpa
Could you help me?

**My steps:**

1. add jar (build path> configure build path > add external jars ... )
2. add to build.sbt: "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100.jdbc4"
3. add to application.conf:

   ```
   db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver

   db.default.url=" jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teste "

   db.default.user="postgres"

   db.default.password="postgre"
   ```

**Result:**
Browser message: Driver not found : [ org.postgresql.Driver ]

**Where is the problem ?**

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL artifacts have moved to a new group ID `org.postgresql`.

```
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4"
```

Comment: Hi Bahman, thank you! 
Your answer solved my problem!
Futhermore, I did this change:
 db.default.url="postgres://postgres:postgre@localhost/teste"